# Why do I get Segmentation Fault on this?

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree

I am trying to arrange a number of words in alphabetical order using a binary search tree. Here is a part of the code:

```
int wordCmp (char a[], char b[])
{
int i = 0;
while(a[i] == b[i])
    ++i;
return a[i] < b[i];
}
void Insert (node* &root , char a[])
{
if(root == NULL)
    root = CreateNewNodde(a);
else
{
    if (wordCmp(a,root -> word))
        Insert(root -> left , a);
    else Insert(root -> right, a);
}
```

}

I get the segmentation fault error on thise instruction:

```
int wordCmp (char a[], char b[])
{
int i = 0;
- > while(a[i] == b[i]) <- Segmentation Fault
    ++i;
return a[i] < b[i];
}
```

Comment: `while(a[i] && a[i] == b[i])`

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be the problem.

Comment: `char*` is not a good way to represent "words". Use `std::string`.

Answer (score 2):

You are indexing outside of the array bounds. In C++ an array does not know its length. Remember that character arrays are "terminated" by having the character '\0' at the end. This value will convert to false in a boolean expression.

Hence you must do

```
int wordCmp (char a[], char b[])
{
    int i = 0;
    while(a[i] && b[i] && a[i] == b[i])
        ++i;
    return a[i] < b[i];
}
```

Note that I am checking that a[i] and b[i] are valid, i.e. they do not contain the '\0'. Also, in C++, expressions are evaluated from left to right, hence
if either a[i] or b[i] contains '\0' then a[i] == b[i] won't be evaluated.
You need to check both a[i] and b[i] as you don't know which char array contains the longest word.

Comment: You actually don't have to check both arrays because if one of them hits `'\0'` before the other, they will not compare equal at that point.

Comment: @BoPersson You're right, checking both a[i] and b[i] is slightly unnecessary.